# Local VBA Help for Office versions later than 2010

Tags: excel, vba, office365

Just switched over to Excel 365 and realized there is no local help.  It's linked to online uS documentation.  So, besides not working quite right, it's slow and unavailable on flights and other places.

Is there a way to download a local copy of the help file that supports the "F1" dance in VBA?  How do you dance?  You select an object and hit F1.

Thank you so much.

I would say, by the way, if I have to do online think I'll go back a purchase a regular copy.  It is so clunky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off-line Help for Office VBA Editor was discontinued after Office 2010 (and even then, it was a fight to have it).

Starting with Office 2013, Help for the VBA Editor is on-line, only and that's the only place to get the context-sensitive F1 help. For 2013 you can download CHM files for the various Office applications: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40326. But you have to open and search, there's no linkage to F1.

For Office 2016 Help CHM files have been made available on GitHub: https://github.com/OfficeDev/VBA-content/tree/05ff968/VBA/Offline-Docs (many thanks to @AntoineL for this information - old link was https://github.com/OfficeDev/VBA-content)

[**Removed**: information on exporting Help topics - the functionality has been removed from the Microsoft site.]

Comment: Also it took me a some time to find the compiled CHM from 2016 on GitHub, since they [dropped them on June 9th 2017](https://github.com/OfficeDev/VBA-content/commit/68c04aa). Git keeps everything so they are [still available](https://github.com/OfficeDev/VBA-content/tree/05ff968/VBA/Offline-Docs) at the parent commit 05ff968...

Answer (score 0):

I think, the documentation is only in Online version, if you have a slow In Office Help, you can search your question on the official support website, https://support.office.com/.

About me, "F1" help is only preview of https://support.office.com/, couse both of them has a same structure.

Comment: It's outrageous!  This company is getting more irritating than usual. :-)  I really wish there was an alternative.  "Networked or go to hell."  Thanks for the answer.